# How to redirect everything internally using htaccess and mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to process all the requests to a domain using a single php script.

For example:

```
www.domain.com/something.php -> would be loading -> www.domain.com/process.php?u=something.php
www.domain.com/anything      -> would be loading -> www.domain.com/process.php?u=anything
www.domain.com/sub/dir/x     -> would be loading -> www.domain.com/process.php?u=sub/dir/x
```

But process.php should never open directly on the browser, I want to do like an internal redirection.

Could someone show me how could I use htaccess and mod_rewrite to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put these lines into your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) process.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will tell Apache to use `process.php` instead of the actually requested page.

Most likely you will also need to add these lines before `RewriteRule` line to tell Apache to process existing files as is, otherwise your images/css/javascript files will also be processed by `process.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```